# How to program swift for OS X on Xcode 6?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have downloaded Xcode 6. I have the option to develop for iOS using swift, but when I try to develop for OSX using swift, I don't get the option to. Any ideas why?

For iOS:
[image: For iOS:]

For OS X
[image: For OSX]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to Xcode 6.1. Xcode 6.0 does not support Swift development on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You have o download Xcode 6.1 to be able to code for OS X using Swift

Answer (score 1):

Get Xcode version at least 6.1 to do that:

[download link](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)